# connect multiple Top-Level-Domains

Tags: seo, domains

My main site is a webbuilder-based website with .com top-Level Domain.
But to be more reputable i also have a .de domain from united-domains that simply refers to that site.

My question is how to connect these sites to get a proper SEO. I have that feeling that goole is ranking these domains different. My .COM DOMAIN has an medium ranking and the .DE isnt even in the top 100.

Important for me are the backlinks: i have many sites and social posts refereing to the .DE domain because it is much more reputable. But NO backlinks to the .COM domain.

1. Is there a way to tell google theses sites are the same(that these are one website)? Is there a special programming? A setting?
2. can the Search engine even connect these domains?

I know the way is not good, but is there any hope or alternative to purging the .DE domain and only using the (for customers ) "untrustworthy" .COM domain? and tell every customer to link me with the .COM domain :(

Comment: Are you located in Germany? Do you serve only German customers?

Comment: When you say "i also have a .de domain from united-domains that simply refers to that site", do you mean it hosts the same content, uses 301 redirects, or has its own content that links to the other site?

Comment: yes german customers.

Comment: the .DE domain is a link to the .COM host. and i think it is a 301 redirect